# Unity / C#: using lists to store numbers, delete elements

Tags: list, unity-game-engine

I have been banging my head on a problem related to lists. I am a beginner, so sorry if this is a bit unclear..

My goal is to be able to write numbers from keyboard inputs, that will be displayed in a UI element in Unity.

To do so i decided to use a list, because i was wanting to add control to the display, (for example, to add a "." every 3 digits so that they would be more easily readable, like "3.489.498").

So basically, i store new inputs in this list, then i display this list with a display.text every time there is a new digit as an input.

This works actually very well, but then i wanted to be able to delete the last typed element. So i added a backspace hotkey with a List.Remove().

And this is where the nightmare starts. The thing seems to work when i press "1" and deletes right after, but for some reasons it does not work with 2.

Error message is : "Argument out of range, parameter name: index."

I just can't wrap my head around this problem :(

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BoxCreateNumber : MonoBehaviour {

public Text textDisplayNumber;
public List<int> numberList = new List<int>();

void Start () {
}

void Update () {
    CollectingNumberInput ();
}

void CollectingNumberInput(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad1)){
        numberList.Add (1);
        //numberList.Insert (numberList.Count,1);
        DisplayNumber ();
    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad2)) {
        numberList.Add (2);
        //numberList.Insert (numberList.Count,2);
        DisplayNumber ();
    } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Backspace)) {
        numberList.Remove(numberList.Count);
        DisplayNumber ();
    }
}

void DisplayNumber(){
    textDisplayNumber.text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberList.Count; i++) {
         textDisplayNumber.text += numberList [i];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to remove the last element

```
numberList.RemoveAt(numberList.Count-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public bool Remove(
    T item
)
```

> Parameters
>
> item - The object to remove from the List. The value can be null for reference types.

Instead of passing the function the object to remove, you pass the number of elements in the list. This means that if the list contains element "1" as its only element, then it will work, but only by accident.

Calling `RemoveAt(numberList.Count - 1)` will do what you want. `RemoveAt` takes the **index** of the element to remove, and the indices are 0-based, so the last one is `Count-1`.

Comment: Oh thank you very much... and thanks for the explanation, i think i get it now ! Brilliant !